# How can we assume the certain probability in probability problem

Tags: probability

I was solving following problem:

> There are $k + 1$ coins in a box. When flipped, the ith coin will turn up heads with probability $i/k, i = 0, 1, . . . , k$. A coin is randomly selected from the box and is then repeatedly flipped. If the first n flips all result in heads, what is the conditional probability that the $(n + 1)$st flip will do likewise?

Solution is given as follows:

> Let $C_i$ denote the event that the $i$th coin, $i = 0, 1, . . . , k$, is initially selected; let $F_n$ denote the event that the first $n$ flips all result in heads; and let $H$ be the event that the $(n + 1)$st flip is a head. The desired probability, $P(H|F_n)$, is now obtained as follows:
>   $$P(H|F_n) = \sum^k_{i=0} P(H|F_nC_i)P(C_i|F_n)$$
>   Now, given that the ith coin is selected, it is reasonable to assume that the outcomes will be conditionally independent, with each one resulting in a head with probability $i/k$. Hence,
>   $$P(H|F_nC_i) = P(H|C_i) = \frac{i}{k}$$
>   (The solution continues further...)

I didnt get following two points:

- How is following assumption correct: $P(H|F_nC_i)=P(H|C_i)$?
- If the author can assume $P(H|F_nC_i)=\frac{i}{k}$, why cant one simply assume $P(H|F_n)=\frac{i}{k}$? (I know thats funny, but still...)

Comment: The only thing that the author *assumes*   is independency of the outcomes. Based on that  it is eventually *conluded* that the probability equals $\frac{i}{k}$. So you cannot qualify that as only an assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Under condition $F_nC_i$ we are dealing with the $i$-th coin. Also there have been $n$ consecutive flips allready resulting in $n$ heads but that is not relevant when it comes to the $n+1$-th flip (a coin has no memory). The only thing that counts is that you flip a coin that gives you a probability of $\frac{i}{k}$ on heads. That explains $P(H\mid F_nC_i)=P(H\mid C_i)=\frac{i}{k}$.
- Note that $P(H\mid F_n)$ is *not* depending on index $i$ while your suggested $\frac{i}{k}$ *does* depend on $i$. That explains why assumption $P(H\mid F_n)=\frac{i}{k}$ is absurd.

Comment: This is from the standard book "First Course in Probability" by Sheldon Ross. There are many such probabilities inferred in different problems in different ways. I am puzzled, how one is supposed to know while solving any given problem how one should infer any possible probability in logical context of given problem?